# Product Create via API - not showing in admin panel

Tags: api, xmlrpc

We create products via the Magento API, these are simple products.

We only have 1 website and 1 store in this website.

We were creating products with store 1 set, these would create the products , but require and update call for them to show in the admin panel / front end.

We have since moved to using store 0 as were informed that store 1 was not actually correct (long story)

Now we have the effect that creating the product will return and ID and it is visible on the front end, but not in the admin panel.

It seems we still requite and update call to 'activate' the product, and then an index + layout cache to be cleared to show in the admin panel.

Is there something we could be missing in the product create call that could be causing this (we let magento create the url-key etc)

We are running 1.9.1.0 and using the XMLRPC API

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 1):

For what its worth the answer was as simple as we were missing the `status` value of `1`.

If we created the product without this, it was hidden in the admin panel.

It appears magento will accept Null / None for this value and carry on.